# Return the number of months between now and datetime value SQL

Tags: sql, date, time, google-bigquery

I apologize, I am new at SQL. I am using BigQuery. I have a field called "last_engaged_date", this field is a datetime value (2021-12-12 00:00:00 UTC). I am trying to perform a count on the number of records that were "engaged" 12 months ago, 18 months ago, and 24 months ago based on this field. At first, to make it simple for myself, I was just trying to get a count of the number of records per year, something like:

```
Select count(id), year(last_engaged_date) as last_engaged_year
from xyz
group by last_engaged_year
order by last_engaged_year asc
```

I know that there are a lot of things wrong with this query but primarily, BQ says that "Year" is not a valid function? Either way, What I really need is something like:

```
Date() - last_engaged_date = int(# of months)
count if <= 12 months as "12_months_count" (# of records where now - last engaged date is less than or equal to 12 months)
count if <= 18 months as "18_months_count"
count if <= 24 months as "24_months_count"
```

So that I have a count of how many records for each last_engaged_date period there are.

I hope this makes sense. Thank you so much for any ideas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [How to] Return the number of months between now and datetime value [in BigQuery] SQL

The simples way is just to use DATE_DIFF function as in below example

```
date_diff(current_date(), date(last_engaged_date), month)
```

Comment: Ah, that's so much more simple than I thought it was. Thank you so much!